# Config file for webpack tutorial does not properly run Babel loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

designer here learning frontend. I know this is probably a really simple issue but I'm doing a tutorial to learn webpack and whenever I run the examples in the github repo they do not work. As I've gone through the sections and I've managed to fix some of the little syntax errors that stopped it from running but after I loaded the babel loader and stuff it isn't working and it is throwing some pretty weird errors that I can't figure out. Since I don't really have much experience with Babel and I'm just adding it to the webpack configuration to learn the ropes but if this is a Babel error, then I'm at a loss.

Here's a link to a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jzq81jo2yv

Also here's what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-practice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project to practice webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "del-cli dist -f",
    "build": "webpack",
    "execute": "node /dist/bundle.js",
    "start": "npm run build -s && npm run execute -s"
  },
  "author": "David Aslan French",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "del-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  }
}
```

and here's what my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I'm also using WSL, Ubuntu on Windows.

Also here is the tutorial I'm following: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/02/a-detailed-introduction-to-webpack/

And here's a link to the github repo:
https://github.com/joezimjs/Webpack-Introduction-Tutorial/tree/example2

Also here's the error log it was giving me:

```
> webpack-practice@1.0.0 start /mnt/c/Users/Owner/Work/Web/Webpack-Practice
> npm run build -s && npm run execute -s

[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "/mnt/c/Users/Owner/Work/Web/Webpack-Practice/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js" as it exceeds the max of "500KB".
Hash: 1111e3ba66d401ede87c
Version: webpack 4.12.0
Time: 3983ms
Built at: 06/19/2018 12:50:31 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  89.4 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
 [31] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 82 bytes {0} [built]
 [47] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 521 bytes {0} [built]
 [99] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 770 bytes {0} [built]
[101] ./src/main.js 133 bytes {0} [built]
    + 98 hidden modules

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/
/dist/bundle.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { !function(t){var n={};function r(e){if(n[e])return n[e].exports;var u=n[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return t[e].call(u.exports,u,u.exports,r),u.l=!0,u.exports}r.m=t,r.c=n,r.d=function(t,n,e){r.o(t,n)||Object.defineProperty(t,n,{enumerable:!0,get:e})},r.r=function(t){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(t,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})},r.t=function(t,n){if(1&n&&(t=r(t)),8&n)return t;if(4&n&&"object"==typeof t&&t&&t.__esModule)return t;var e=Object.create(null);if(r.r(e),Object.defineProperty(e,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:t}),2&n&&"string"!=typeof t)for(var u in t)r.d(e,u,function(n){return t[n]}.bind(null,u));return e},r.n=function(t){var n=t&&t.__esModule?function(){return t.default}:function(){return t};return r.d(n,"a",n),n},r.o=function(t,n){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,n)},r.p="",r(r.s=101)}([function(t,n,r){"use strict"

TypeError: e is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dist/bundle.js:1:19168)
    at r (/dist/bundle.js:1:172)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dist/bundle.js:1:19248)
    at r (/dist/bundle.js:1:172)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dist/bundle.js:1:19379)
    at r (/dist/bundle.js:1:172)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dist/bundle.js:1:1816)
    at r (/dist/bundle.js:1:172)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dist/bundle.js:1:3186)
    at r (/dist/bundle.js:1:172)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-practice@1.0.0 start: `npm run build -s && npm run execute -s`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-practice@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/david/.npm/_logs/2018-06-19T18_50_32_168Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is the error message that you are seeing when you build?

Comment: I am currently on my phone but a wild guess. Does the babel-loader maybe has the wrong version? All other babel modules are on version 6.x. What is the error you got?

Comment: Sorry, I totally should have included the error logs, dumb error on my part. 

I found the answer though after going through his repo some more. The issue was that I didn't know from the tutorial that I was supposed to exclude babel from node modules. It was trying to babel process the webpack js. So fixed that! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I'm an idiot. I went through his repo again and I noticed that he included a statement about excludinging node modules in the webpack.config.js file. here's the proper version of the webpack file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                // blacklist node_modules scripts from being processed via Babel
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    // prevents multiple versions of e.g. regeneratorRuntime from
                    // being created when using generators in multiple files
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    // tell Babel which presets to use
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```